# Routing and DHCP on Switch (tp-link T1600G-28TS)

Tags: networking, routing, router, switch, gateway

i wanted to set up a "smart" switch (tp-link T1600G-28TS) for creating my own subnet with its own DHCP.

I get internet through a single Ethernet-Jack. Behind this ethernet jack is a gateway. The IPs get distributed per DHCP.

I connected Port 1 of my switch with the ethernet jack.

### Network looks like this

```
10.10.0.0/16 (the network where my ethernet jack is in, internet is here)
 |
10.10.254.254 (the gateway)
 |
the ethernet jack
 |
192.168.0.1 (my switch)
 |
192.168.0.0/24 (my network, IPs get distributed by my switch)
```

### The problem

The DHCP Server works fine but I have **no internet connection** in my network `192.168.0.0/24`.

My switch supports static routing, DHCP server and DHCP relay (see https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/smart-switch/t1600g-28ts/#specifications), is this enough?

### Config of the switch

I did besides the DHCP server the following configurations:

**1. Interface settings**

**1.1. First entry**

- Interface ID: Gi1/0/1 (Port 1)
- IP Address Mode: DHCP
- IP Address: 10.10.252.200
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
- Status: Up

**1.2. Second entry**

- Interface ID: VLAN1 (was set by switch, Port 2 to 28)
- IP Address Mode: Static
- IP Address: 192.168.0.1
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Status: Up

**2. Static Routing**

I did no entries here since I don't know what to enter. The following values are needed:

- Destination
- Subnet Mask
- Next Hop
- Distance (optional)

### Summary

Is my configuration incorrect, is something missing or is it even possible? Do I need a router instead?

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear this switch provides a DHCP server, which is normal for a switch.  Normally, you would configure one of the servers on your network to provide DHCP services.  However, It is common for gateway devices to provide both NAT and DHCP services. If your gateway, provides these services use them.

If not, you will also need to provide DHCP and DNS masquerading (SNAT) services neither of which it appears that the switch will provide.  I would not provide an IP address on the external (10.0.0.0/8) network on the switch.  The external IP address should be on the server that is providing SNAT services, which can also be the same host the provides DHCP services.

The most secure solution would be to provide DHCP and SNAT on a device between the switch and the gateway.  This will require a second Ethernet interface on that system.